# How to access HTML from iframe

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have a structure like

```
<iframe tabindex="2" class="s-basicpanel s-panel-border" id="test1">
  <html>
   <body id ="test"></body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

I have to add inner text to the body tag.

I did the following:

```
public void testData()
{
    mshtml.IHTMLWindow2 frame2 = IEDOMDocument.frames.item(ref 0);
    if (frame2 != null)
    {
        if(frame2.document.body != null)
        {
            mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection  allElements = (mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection)frame2.document.body.all;
            foreach(mshtml.IHTMLElement test in  allElements)
            {
                Log("Tag Name:"+test.tagName);
                if(test.tagName.ToLower() == "iframe")
                {
                    string iframeId=test.getAttribute("id").ToString();
                    if(iframeId.Equals("test1"))
                    {
                        Log("found elemnet***");
                        mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection collection = (mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection)test.children; // return me empty collection
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using above code when I am trying to access the inner collection within iframe, it provides me empty collection.

**After lot's of debugging i got to know that problem is with the data from iframe.**
I need someone to help with the same.